# Get object value using an array to find the object key

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object:

```
const object = {
  lvl1: {
    dogs: "bark",
    lvl2: {
      cats: "meow",
      lvl3: {
        cows: "moo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
const array1 = ["lvl1", "lvl2", "cats"]
const array2 = ["lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3", "cows"]
```

How do I create a function that returns the value of `cats` and `cows` with only the array as an input parameter?

Let's say the function is called `getValue()`.

If `const value1 = getValue(array1)` were called, it should be equivalent to:

```
const value1 = object["lvl1"]["lvl2"]["cats"]
```

If `const value2 = getValue(array2)` were called, it should be equivalent to:

```
const value2 = object["lvl1"]["lvl2"]["lvl3"]["cows"]
```

This is my attempt so far but it's not working:

```
  const getValue = (array) => {
    let o = object;
    let newObject = o;
    array.forEach((key) => (o = o[key]));
    return newObject ;
  };
```

Comment: The linked question's answers start with a string, but then they split it into an array, at which point they apply to the above.

Comment: You are almost there. Inside `getValue`, do `return o` instead of `return newObject`

Comment: Yeah you're right. I also needed to set `o` to `let o = { ...object }`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since you are reassigning `o = o[key]`, it will just change `o` and not the original `object`. So, cloning is not really required.